# Could not start heartbeat

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, heartbeat, heartbeat1

I am having following erro when starting heartbeat. What is the problem?

```
    # service heartbeat start
    Starting High-Availability services: IPaddr[16856]: INFO:  Running OK
    ResourceManager[16833]: CRITICAL: Resource IPaddr::47.168.96.10 is active, and should not be!
    ResourceManager[16833]: CRITICAL: Non-idle resources can affect data integrity!
    ResourceManager[16833]: info: If you don't know what this means, then get help!
    ResourceManager[16833]: info: Read the docs and/or source to /usr/share/heartbeat/ResourceManager for more details.
    CRITICAL: Resource IPaddr::47.168.96.10 is active, and should not be!
    CRITICAL: Non-idle resources can affect data integrity!
    info: If you don't know what this means, then get help!
    info: Read the docs and/or the source to /usr/share/heartbeat/ResourceManager for more details.
    ResourceManager[16833]: CRITICAL: Non-idle resources will affect resource takeback!
    ResourceManager[16833]: CRITICAL: Non-idle resources may affect data integrity!
    Done.
```

my interface:

```
    eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:17:a4:12:e6:ee
              inet addr:47.168.96.48  Bcast:47.168.96.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::217:a4ff:fe12:e6ee/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:1109187 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:1144245 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
              RX bytes:335466263 (335.4 MB)  TX bytes:810577087 (810.5 MB)
              Interrupt:17

    eth1:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:17:a4:12:e6:ee
              inet addr:47.168.96.10  Bcast:47.168.96.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              Interrupt:17
```

here is ha.conf

```
    logfile /var/log/ha-log
    debugfile /var/log/ha-debug
    autojoin none
    ucast eth1 node1
    ucast eth1 node1
    udpport 694
    warntime 3
    deadtime 5
    initdead 10
    keepalive 1
    node node1 node2
    auto_failback on
```

here is hareresouces

```
cat haresources
node1IPaddr::47.168.96.10 failback.sh
```

**eth confs after heartbeat started.**

```
    //NODE1
            /resource.d# service heartbeat start
    Starting High-Availability services: IPaddr[4050]: INFO:  Resource is stopped
    Done.

    /etc/heartbeat# ip addr show
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
        inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
        inet6 ::1/128 scope host
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
        link/ether 00:17:a4:12:e6:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 47.168.96.48/24 brd 47.168.96.255 scope global eth0
        inet6 fe80::217:a4ff:fe12:e6ee/64 scope link
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
        link/ether 00:04:75:f8:0a:a6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet6 fe80::204:75ff:fef8:aa6/64 scope link
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    root@node1:/etc/heartbeat#

        //NODE2
                    /resource.d# service heartbeat start
    Starting High-Availability services: IPaddr[4050]: INFO:  Resource is stopped
    Done.

    /etc/heartbeat/resource.d# ip addr show
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
        inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
        inet6 ::1/128 scope host
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    2: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
        link/ether 80:1f:02:2f:52:d7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet6 fe80::821f:2ff:fe2f:52d7/64 scope link
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
        link/ether 00:17:a4:17:52:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 47.168.96.46/24 brd 47.168.96.255 scope global eth0
        inet6 fe80::217:a4ff:fe17:5209/64 scope link
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    root@node2:/etc/heartbeat/resource.d#
```

Comment: can we please get an update of what happened after you followed quanta's advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CRITICAL: Resource IPaddr::47.168.96.10 is active, and should not be!
```

Looks like you've setup a dummy alias interface:

```
eth1:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:17:a4:12:e6:ee
          inet addr:47.168.96.10  Bcast:47.168.96.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:17
```

This is unnecessary, Heartbeat will do it for you. Remove this alias from `/etc/network/interfaces` then try again.

Comment: per link http://tipstricks.itmatrix.eu/?p=861, It is mentioned to create virtual ethernet before starting heartbeat

Comment: Could you please show me that part?

Comment: here is the statement mentioned "- Assign the Virtual IP from both servers: VIP=192.168.10.10"

Comment: Just try my suggestion to see what happens.

Comment: I have tried but although heartbeat get started without any error there is no eth is created

Comment: `ip addr show`?

Comment: added/updated the question. pls find them at above

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7608/discussion-between-quanta-and-mmc18)

Comment: cat haresources
node1IPaddr::47.168.96.10/24 failback.sh. Which is corrected the issue.